# subprocess cannot run python executable in non-interactive mode?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, interpreter

I am using python 3.6.3 and `subprocess` module to run another python script

```
#  main.py

#!/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
from sys import executable

p = Popen([executable, 'test.py', 'arg1'],shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
p.wait()
print(p.stdout.read().decode())
```

and

```
#  test.py

import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

I expect it will run and execute `test.py`. However, it opens an python interpreter in interactive mode!

I tested `shell=False` option, it works. I tested string form rather than list form of `args`, it works.

I am not sure if it is a bug or not.

Comment: CPython will drop to interactive mode if it's `stdin` is connected to a TTY. The default of Popen is for the default io handles to be inherited, which connects the second interpreter to your TTY as well. Try passing `stdin=None`.

Comment: @user2722968 I'm unable to see that behavior with Python 3.6.5rc1. If I run `python3 test.py arg1` from my terminal (where stdin is a tty), it runs the script without dropping to an interactive shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `shell=True` or change the first argument to be `executable + ' test.py arg1'` instead of `[executable, 'test.py', 'arg1']`.

As explained in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), with `shell = True`, it will run it as `/bin/sh -c python test.py arg1`, which means `python` will be run without arguments.

Comment: This is horrible and will lead to problems with more complex arguments

Comment: It is reasonable, the docs explain how it works. What can really lead to problems is using something without understanding how it works.